# One Port has 2 status (established and listen), how can it happen?

Tags: http, webserver, port, websphere-liberty, tcp

I'm monitoring my server's port assignment and found a strange thing...

I used IBM Websphere Liberty and found that one port has 2 status(listening and established...), that's odd...

[image]

10318 is my listening port for this liberty server...But it has 2 status...

So could anyone can explain to me about this?

I thought that one port can only has one status at one time...

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is routine for any TCP listening port that ever gets used. When it's idle, there's a single listening socket in netstat. For each client connected to that port, there's also an established socket.

Comment: @covener Thanks for your answer! I'm just not familiar with TCP/IP protocol... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the connection number is different between the listener and established sockets.  As long as the combination of the 4 numbers of local port and socket and foreign port and socket is unique, you can establish multiple sockets, ie in your netstat output, 9.20.4.125..3305 can't establish another connection to 9.20.4.125..10318.